# Reflection Exception by request.getParameter

Tags: java, jsp

Recently we got a review by the audit team, There we have seen the Reflection XSS vulnerability

> String s=request.getParameter("sname");

and we have tried with StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml

but unable to resolve the issue. please help

Comment: which version of `StringEscapeUtils`  & HTML you are using currently

Comment: Can you add more detail on what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve? See [ask].

Comment: resolve the issue with version 3.12 and thanks for the support @AshishPatil

Comment: @TrySan , glad to know issue is resolved.

Comment: Can you please help me out, with how to resolve the SQL injection without changing the value to preparedStatement in java @AshishPatil

Comment: You might need to share more details @TrySan, may be post another question of your new requirement?

Comment: @AshishPatil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72307072/preventing-the-sql-injection-in-statement?noredirect=1#comment127742940_72307072

Comment: @TrySan , yeah I checked but as per comment it looks like this already has answer or something?